# Seven Segment Display XNA

Tags: c#, .net, xna, xna-4.0

I'm trying to draw a Seven Segment display using this following method, I can't see why, even when I run through the debugger, but for somereason it doesn't display the numbers. What is wrong here? You can ignore the large array, it's just to show how I store the values.

```
    private void DrawScore(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, int score, int playerNumber)
    {
        int[,,] numbers =
            {
                // Zero 
                // Output: 
                // [ ][.][ ]  [.] = white square [ ] = black square
                // [.][ ][.]
                // [ ][.][ ]
                // [.][ ][.]
                // [ ][.][ ]   
                {
                    {0, 1, 0},
                    {1, 0, 1},
                    {0, 0, 0},
                    {1, 0, 1},
                    {0, 1, 0}
                },
                {
                    {0, 0, 0},
                    {0, 0, 1},
                    {0, 0, 0},
                    {0, 0, 1},
                    {0, 0, 0}
                },
                {
                    {0, 1, 0},
                    {0, 0, 1},
                    {0, 1, 0},
                    {1, 0, 0},
                    {0, 1, 0}
                },

                {
                    {0, 1, 0},
                    {0, 0, 1},
                    {0, 1, 0},
                    {0, 0, 1},
                    {0, 1, 0}
                },
                {
                    {0, 0, 0},
                    {1, 0, 1},
                    {0, 1, 0},
                    {0, 0, 1},
                    {0, 0, 0}
                },
                {
                    {0, 1, 0},
                    {1, 0, 0},
                    {0, 1, 0},
                    {0, 0, 1},
                    {0, 1, 0}
                },
                {
                    {0, 1, 0},
                    {1, 0, 0},
                    {0, 1, 0},
                    {1, 0, 1},
                    {0, 1, 0}
                },
                {
                    {0, 1, 0},
                    {0, 0, 1},
                    {0, 0, 0},
                    {0, 0, 1},
                    {0, 0, 0}
                },
                {
                    {0, 1, 0},
                    {1, 0, 1},
                    {0, 1, 0},
                    {1, 0, 1},
                    {0, 1, 0}
                },
                {
                    {0, 1, 0},
                    {1, 0, 1},
                    {0, 1, 0},
                    {0, 0, 1},
                    {0, 0, 0}
                }
            };

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers.GetLength(2); j++)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Score: {0}", score);
                Debug.WriteLine("\ti, j: {0}", numbers[score, i, j]);
                if (playerNumber == 1)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(numbers[score, i, j] == 0 ? _scoreSegmentTexBlack : _scoreSegmentTexWhite,
                                     new Vector2(
                                         (Graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth/2) - _scoreSegmentTex.Width*(3 + i),
                                         _scoreSegmentTex.Height*j + 1),
                                     Color.White);
                }
                if (playerNumber == 2)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(numbers[score, i, j] == 0 ? _scoreSegmentTexBlack : _scoreSegmentTexWhite,
                                     new Vector2(
                                         (Graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / 2) + _scoreSegmentTex.Width*(1 + i),
                                         _scoreSegmentTex.Height*j + 1),
                                     Color.White);
                }
            }
        }



    }
```

Comment: I assume two levels of looping (i, j) thru a large array, are what causes the slowness? I don't see anything else. And why the "big opaque gumbo" of your "numbers" array, and no clear/ meaningful structure such as "digits" or "segments"?

Comment: Each section of 2d array is a different number starting at 0, my bad for not commenting.

Comment: It's probably easier and faster to store the numbers as entire textures instead of building them. Apart from that I really don't see how your array is structured. Why are there three entries per inner array and five arrays in the middle array, producing 15 entries per digit. Doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Precisely @NicoSchertler. A class 'DigitFigure' with a list of Segments would be clear.. Segments can be enums or constants. But this code isn't. There aren't any common subexpressions or meaningful variables.. just a glob.

Comment: Each digit need 15 "segments" to display it, 8 segments are already black no matter what because it draws a rectangle and I fit the 7 segment display inside of the 15 segment display. If you look at the shape of each 2d array, it's a shape of '1's starting at 0 then proceeding up to 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to make a whole class to handle this instead.

Pictured below is '0' drawn at (0, 0). (x = 0, y = 0) Using the code below:

```
SevenSegmentDisplay myDisplay = new SevenSegmentDisplay(0, 0);
// Inside the game loop somewhere.
if (playerScoreCondition) {
    // player.Score++;
    // In this case score is still 0.
    myDisplay.Update(player.Score);    
}
// Draw
myDisplay.Draw(spriteBatch, segmentTexture, scoreDisplayX, scoreDisplayY, Color.White, new Color(30, 30, 30, 255));
```

[image: A picture of the seven segment display drawn at 0]

```
internal class SevenSegmentDisplay
{
    private int a, b, c, d, e, f, g;

    private readonly int[,] numbers;

    public SevenSegmentDisplay()
    {
        numbers = new[,] {
              /* Format is A - G, see: 
               * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display
               */
              // 0
              {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
              // 1
              {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
              // 2
              {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1},
              // 3
              {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1},
              // 4
              {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1},
              // 5
              {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
              // 6
              {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
              // 7
              {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
              // 8
              {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
              // 9
              {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}
        };
        // Initialize each segment to 0 (black)
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        c = 0;
        d = 0;
        e = 0;
        f = 0;
        g = 0;
    }

    private void Update(IList<int> i)
    {
        // Update each segment
        a = i[0];
        b = i[1];
        c = i[2];
        d = i[3];
        e = i[4];
        f = i[5];
        g = i[6];
    }

    public void Update(int i)
    {
        Update(IntToSevenSegment(i));
    }

    private int[] IntToSevenSegment(int i)
    {
        int[] temp = new int[7];

        for (int counter = 0; counter < 7; counter++)
            temp[counter] = numbers[i, counter];

        return temp;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Texture2D texture, int x, int y, Color on, Color off)
    {
        // Texture should be a white square, to handle the drawing of each segment.
        // Handle each segment A - G and draw them according to their positions depending on the texture size.

        Rectangle a = new Rectangle(x + texture.Width, y, texture.Width*2, texture.Height);
        Rectangle b = new Rectangle(x + texture.Width*3, y + texture.Height, texture.Width, texture.Height*2);
        Rectangle c = new Rectangle(x + texture.Width*3, y + texture.Height*4, texture.Width, texture.Height*2);
        Rectangle d = new Rectangle(x + texture.Width, y + texture.Height*6, texture.Width*2, texture.Height);
        Rectangle e = new Rectangle(x, y + texture.Height*4, texture.Width, texture.Height*2);
        Rectangle f = new Rectangle(x, y + texture.Height, texture.Width, texture.Height*2);
        Rectangle g = new Rectangle(x + texture.Width, y + texture.Height*3, texture.Width*2, texture.Height);

        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, a, this.a == 1 ? on : off);
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, b, this.b == 1 ? on : off);
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, c, this.c == 1 ? on : off);
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, d, this.d == 1 ? on : off);
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, e, this.e == 1 ? on : off);
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, f, this.f == 1 ? on : off);
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, g, this.g == 1 ? on : off);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java:

```
public class Digit {
    protected int value;
    protected List<Segment> segmentList;

    public Digit (int value, Segment... segments) {
        this.value = value;
        this.segmentList = Arrays.asList( segments);
    }

    public void draw (int x, int y) {
        for (Segment seg : segmentList) {
            seg.draw( x, y);
        }
    }
}

public enum Segment {
    TOP (0, 0, 1, 0),    // x0,y0, x1,y1
    LT  (0, 0, 0, 1),
    RT  (1, 0, 1, 1),
    MID (0, 1, 1, 1),
    LB  (0, 1, 0, 2),
    RB  (1, 1, 1, 2),
    BOT (0, 2, 1, 2);
    private Segment (int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1) {
         // assign x0,y0 & x1,y1 to fields.
    }
    public draw (int xofs, int yofs) {
         // draw..
    }
}



// setup the Digits somewhere..  then:

public void drawScore (int number, int xofs, int yofs) {
    int remain = number;
    int digitI = 0;
    while (remain > 0 || digitI == 0) {
        int digit = (remain % 10);
        remain /= 10;

        // draw the digit.
        //
        int xpos = digit * DIGIT_WIDTH;
        digits[digit].draw( xpos, SCORE_YPOS);
    }
}
```